# How to implement a nested for loop in functional programming in python?

Tags: python, loops, functional-programming

I was thinking of applying the map function twice in order to allow it to act as a double for loop but I don't know if that makes sense. 
Is that the way to go about it?

For example, this is what I am working on:

In imperative:

```
def degree(A):
    n = len(A)
    t = []
    for i in range(n):
        d = 0
        for j in range(n):
            d+=A[i][j]
        t.append(d)

    return t
```

In functional:

```
def degree(A):
    n = len(A)
    t = []
    map(lambda x,y:x+y,A)
```

If it was a single for loop then I would approach it as I did above. So I was trying to implement a double map, but I do not know what how to structure that.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You do much more than just have a double loop, you also create a sum in the inner loop.

Comment: You could get the same effect with `map(sum, A)`, by the way, no need to nest anything.

Comment: Your attempt at `map()` doesn't make any sense in your context; where you thinking of `reduce()` perhaps? `map()` takes any number of iterables, and applies those together as inputs, but `map(..., A)` only has **one** input, so *one* argument for the lambda. You then build a sequence of results, not a total sum. `reduce()` produces a single result from repeated calls to a function and the input sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are summing the inner lists `A`, so just apply `sum` to each nested list in `A`:

```
def degree(A):
    return map(sum, A)
```

You could also consider using a list comprehension or generator expression (depending on whether or not you need to produce the result lazily (`map()` in Python 2 produces a list, in Python 3 it works lazily):

```
def degree(A):
    # returns a list
    return [sum(row) for row in A]

def degree(A):
    # returns a generator
    return (sum(row) for row in A)
```

You can otherwise produce `i` and `j` as a *cartesian product*, using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product); however, you'd be passing in a *tuple* of integers to the map callable:

```
from itertools import product

map(lambda ij: A[ij[0]][ij[1]] ** 2, product(range(len(A)), 2))
```

This can be remedied by using [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

starmap(lambda i, j: A[i][i] ** 2, product(range(len(A)), 2))
```

Neither produces a sum; I demoed a `lambda` that produces the square of the innermost values instead, so you get one long sequence of all values, squared, without distinction between rows. That's how mapping works, it produces a value *per item processed in the input*.

You could also just *nest* the `map()` calls; put the inner `map()` in the callable for the outer `map()`:

```
map(lambda r: map(lambda v: v ** 2, r), A)
```

but note that this then produces a lazy sequence of lazy objects in Python 3. Again, summing doesn't make sense in this scenario, as there is no accumulation of results.

For a generic *cumulation* of results across a sequence, you want to use the [`functools.reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); *that* callable applies a callable on a running result and the next value in a sequence. You can produce a sum with your `lambda x, y: x + y` function and `map()`:

```
map(lambda r: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, r, 0), A)
```

But for *just summing*, the `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, <iterable>, 0)` syntax is just a verbose and slower way of spelling `sum(<iterable>)`.

Comment: so I am wondering how would that take care of the A[i][j] part, the matrix that is formed with the double loop?

Comment: are both those methods equivalent?

Comment: @ce1: both what methods? No, the `product()` method doesn't produce the same results; you can't produce the same results with `product()` as you reset `d` each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: If the line were to be d+=A[i][j] * X[j] where X is a list passed to the function, how would the map(sum, A) change in functional programming?

Comment: @ce1: use `zip()` to pair up rows from `A` with `X`: `(sum(a * x for a, x in zip(r, X) for r in A)` in a generator expression, or `from operator import mul` then `map(lambda r: sum(map(prod, r, X)), A)` if you must use `map()` over comprehensions.